# What HTML standard should I use at this time?

Tags: html, html4

I know and use basic HTML, but am coming up to speed on the details needed to build an entire complex public site.  Which HTML should be my focus for not only study but for the final site as well?  Thanks so much...RG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason not to use `<!DOCTYPE html>`, as it will work in essentially all browsers that are in use.  I would be a little more selective about the individual features of HTML5 - they are not fully supported by many very popular browsers without javascript polyfills.

Comment: Can you give me some particular examples?  And, I guess my choices would then be to avoid the features, notify the user that their browser is not supported, or provide shims to fix the holes?  Thanks...

Comment: There are many sites that describe the HTML5 capabilities of browsers. Here's one: http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus

Answer (score 2):

You should focus on HTML5, it will become standard very soon.

Comment: I was kind of leaning that way but am a bit squeamish about the impact.  Thanks.